# awk count unique occurrences and print other columns

Tags: awk, uniq

I have the following piece of code:

```
awk '{h[$1]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k]}' ${infile} >> ${outfile2}
```

Which does part of what I want: printing out the unique values and then also counting how many times these unique values have occurred. Now, I want to print out the 2nd and 3rd column as well from each unique value. For some reason the following does not seem to work:

```
awk '{h[$1]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, $2, $3, h[k]}' ${infile} >> ${outfile2}
awk '{h[$1]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[$2], h[$3], h[k]}' ${infile} >> ${outfile2}
```

The first prints out the last index's 2nd and 3rd column, whereas the second code prints out nothing except k and h[k].

${infile} would look like:

```
20600        33.8318 -111.9286       -1     0.00        0
20600        33.8318 -111.9286       -1     0.00        0
30900        33.3979 -111.8140       -1     0.00        0
29400        33.9455 -113.5430       -1     0.00        0
30600        33.4461 -111.7876       -1     0.00        0
20600        33.8318 -111.9286       -1     0.00        0
30900        33.3979 -111.8140       -1     0.00        0
30600        33.4461 -111.7876       -1     0.00        0
```

The desired output would be:

```
20600, 33.8318, -111.9286, 3
30900, 33.3979, -111.8140, 2
29400, 33.9455, -113.5430, 1
30600, 33.4461, -111.7876, 2
```

Comment: you have to store the whole value of a line so you can print it out inside the `END` block. `$2`, and `$3` would only be from the last line of input that was read, but your `h[]` (array) will have many entries. In think you'll need another array so you can reference the correct `NR` from your uniq list (but don't have time to test this now). Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close and you can do it all in `awk`, but if you are going to store the count based on field 1 and also have field 2 and field 3 available in `END` to output, you also need to store field 2 & 3 in arrays indexed by field 1 (or whatever field you are keeping count of). For example you could do:

```
awk -v OFS=', ' '
    { h[$1]++; i[$1]=$2; j[$1]=$3 }
    END { 
        for (a in h)
            print a, i[a], j[a], h[a]
        }
' infile
```

Where `h[$1]` holds the count of the number of times field 1 is seen indexing the array with field 1. `i[$1]=$2` captures field 2 indexed by field 1, and then `j[$1]=$3` captures field 3 indexed by field 1.

Then within `END` all that is needed is to output field 1 (`a` the index of `h`), `i[a]` (field 2), `j[a]` (field 3), and finally `h[a]` the count of the number of times field 1 was seen.

**Example Use/Output**

Using your example data, you can just copy/middle-mouse-paste the code at the terminal with the correct filename, e.g.

```
$ awk -v OFS=', ' '
>     { h[$1]++; i[$1]=$2; j[$1]=$3 }
>     END {
>         for (a in h)
>             print a, i[a], j[a], h[a]
>         }
> ' infile
20600, 33.8318, -111.9286, 3
29400, 33.9455, -113.5430, 1
30600, 33.4461, -111.7876, 2
30900, 33.3979, -111.8140, 2
```

Which provides the output desired. If you need to preserve the order of records in the order of the output you show, you can use string-concatenation to group fields 1, 2 & 3 as the index of the array and then output the array and index, e.g.

```
$ awk '{a[$1", "$2", "$3]++}END{for(i in a) print i ", " a[i]}' infile
20600, 33.8318, -111.9286, 3
30600, 33.4461, -111.7876, 2
29400, 33.9455, -113.5430, 1
30900, 33.3979, -111.8140, 2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you. I added a grouping to preserve the output order which does the same thing, but is a bit a-typical in using concatenation of the index.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is a very handy tool for working on groups of columnar data in files that makes this trivial to do.

Assuming your file uses tabs to separate columns like it appears to:

```
$ datamash -s --output-delimiter=, -g 1,2,3 count 3 < input.tsv
20600,33.8318,-111.9286,3
29400,33.9455,-113.5430,1
30600,33.4461,-111.7876,2
30900,33.3979,-111.8140,2
```

Though it's not much more complicated in awk, using a multi dimensional array:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=SUBSEP="," }
       { group[$1,$2,$3]++ }
       END { for (g in group) print g, group[g] }' input.tsv
29400,33.9455,-113.5430,1
30600,33.4461,-111.7876,2
20600,33.8318,-111.9286,3
30900,33.3979,-111.8140,2
```

If you want sorted output instead of random order for this one, if using GNU awk, add a `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"` in the `BEGIN` block, or otherwise pipe the output through `sort`.

You can also get the same effect by pipelining a bunch of utilities (including awk and uniq):

```
$ sort -k1,3n input.tsv | cut -f1-3 | uniq -c | awk -v OFS=, '{ print $2, $3, $4, $1 }' 
20600,33.8318,-111.9286,3
29400,33.9455,-113.5430,1
30600,33.4461,-111.7876,2
30900,33.3979,-111.8140,2
```