# count distinct users - shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

==> user.application.2020-01-16-00-00.csv

```
user1,app1
user1,app2
user2,app1
user3,app1
```

==> user.application.2020-01-16-00-30.csv

```
user1,app1
user2,app1
user2,app4
user10,app2
user10,app1
user4,app5
```

I want output like as follows, app followed by distinct number of users

```
app1,4
app2,2
app4,1
app5,1
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I tried various awk, sort, uniq combination but couldn't get the solution

Comment: Then show us even failed attempts

Comment: I tried the solution here but couldn't get working for my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530186/awk-count-unique-occurrences-and-print-other-columns

Comment: Please show output of this command: `file user.application.2020-01-16-00-00.csv`.

Comment: user.application.2020-01-16-00-00.csv: ASCII text

Comment: shouldn't the count of `app1` be `5`?

Comment: A post not to be taken seriously (I recommend using `awk`): `cat user.*.csv | cut -d , -f 2 | sort -u | while read -r app; do lines=$(cat user.*.csv | grep "$app$" | sort -u | wc -l); echo "$app,$lines"; done`

Comment: @Fravadona It should be 4. app1 has 4 distinct users: user1, user2, user3 and user10

Comment: @Cyrus worked like gold! Thanks. In reality these csv files will be in GB size. Thats why i thought an awk solution would be more performant. Kindly excuse me, i will keep this ticket open to see if we get an awk based solution. I am also trying my best.

Comment: please update the question with your actual code attempts (do not provide links to other posts); also update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code attempt(s); not everyone is going to read through comments trying to piece together the bigger picture and ... code is harder to read when squished into a comment block

Comment: what version of `awk` do you have? please update the question with the output from `awk --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all combinations in an array and print the length of the array.

`awk -F, '{a[$2][$1]} END { for (i in a) { print i "," length(a[i]) } }' *.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your input samples to make visibly explicit the handling of the input, that it does not do automatic sort.

```
#!/bin/sh

DBG=0

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `

TEST_INPUT1="${BASE}_input_1.txt"
TEST_INPUT2="${BASE}_input_2.txt"

cat >"${TEST_INPUT1}" <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
user1,app1
user10,app2
user1,app2
user2,app1
user3,app1
!EnDoFiNpUt

cat >"${TEST_INPUT2}" <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
user1,app1
user2,app1
user2,app5
user10,app2
user10,app1
user4,app4
!EnDoFiNpUt

cat "${TEST_INPUT1}" "${TEST_INPUT2}" |
awk -F "," -v dbg="${DBG}" 'BEGIN{
    ### initialize arrays
    split("", apps ) ;
    split("", usage ) ;
    split("", users ) ;

    ### initialize arrays counter
    indexApps=0 ;
    indexUsers=0 ;
}
{
    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\nLINE:   ", $0 ; } ;
    hit=0 ;

    if( indexApps == 0 ){
        indexApps=1 ;
        apps[1]=$2 ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [0] new app -> ", apps[1] ; } ;

        indexUsers=1 ;
        usage[ indexApps, 1 ]=$2 ;
        usage[ indexApps, 2 ]=1 ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [0]", apps[ indexApps ], " -> ", usage[ indexApps, 2 ] ; } ;

        users[ indexApps, 1 ]=indexUsers ;
        users[ indexApps, indexUsers+1 ]=$1 ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [0] users[", indexApps, " , ", indexUsers+1 " ]  -> ", users[ indexApps, indexUsers+1 ] ; } ;
    }else{
        for( i=1 ; i <= indexApps ; i++ ){
            if( $2 == apps[i] ){
                hit=1 ;
                if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1] users[i,1] = ", users[i,1] ; } ;

                hitU=0 ;
                for( j=1 ; j <= users[i, 1] ; j++ ){
                    if( users[i,j+1] == $1 ){
                        hitU=1 ;
                        if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1]     exists -> ", users[i,j+1] ; } ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
                } ;
                if( hitU == 0 ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1] Hit:  usage BEFORE  ", apps[i], " -> ", usage[i,2] ; } ;
                    usage[i,2]++ ;
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1] Hit:                ", apps[i], " -> ", usage[i,2] ; } ;

                    indexUsers=users[i,1]+1 ;
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1] users[i,1] + 1 = ", indexUsers ; } ;
                    users[ i, 1 ]= indexUsers ;
                    users[ i, indexUsers+1 ]=$1 ;
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [1] users[", i, " , ", indexUsers+1 " ]  -> ", users[ i, indexUsers+1 ] ; } ;
                } ;
                break ;
            } ;
        } ;

        if( hit == 0 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2] NO hit ------------------------------- START" ; } ;
            indexApps++ ;
            apps[ indexApps ]=$2 ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2] new app -> ", apps[ indexApps ] ; } ;

            usage[ indexApps, 1 ]=$2 ;
            usage[ indexApps, 2 ]=1 ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2]", apps[ indexApps ], " -> ", usage[ indexApps, 2 ] ; } ;

            indexUsers=users[ indexApps, 1 ]+1 ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2] users[ indexApps, 1 ] + 1 = ", indexUsers ; } ;
            users[ indexApps, 1 ]= indexUsers ;
            users[ indexApps, indexUsers+1 ]=$1 ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2] users[", indexApps, " , ", indexUsers+1 " ]  -> ", users[ indexApps, iindexUsers+1 ] ; } ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "\t [2] NO hit ------------------------------- END" ; } ;
        } ;
    } ;
}END{
    print "Application Usage:" ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= indexApps ; i++ ){
        printf("  %s = %3d\t", usage[i,1], usage[i,2] ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j <= users[i,1] ; j++ ){
            printf("\t%s", users[i,j+1] ) ;
            if( j > 10 ){ break ; } ;
        } ;
        print "" ;
    } ;
}'
```

The session output is as follows:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$ ./test_47.sh
Application Usage:
  app1 =   4        user1   user2   user3   user10
  app2 =   2        user10  user1
  app5 =   1        user2
  app4 =   1        user4
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$
```